# Find mutually orthogonal vectors given 1 vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Given vector P = [1, 1.25, -0.518]  I would like to find two mutually orthogonal vectors Q and R such that P = Q x R , R = P x Q and Q = R x P.

I'm sure there must be a simple way to do this yet I cannot seem to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Might have something to do with using the fact that orthogonality is defined as meaning the dot product of the two vectors is 0.

Comment: right, the only issue is there is no way to guarantee that the cross product conditions will be satisfied....

Comment: if I only use the dot product

Comment: Are you sure you can't come up with a system of equations from that? I'll wrote some stuff out as an "answer" and it can be edited.

Comment: Try Gram Schmidt on $P,e_1,e_2,e_3$ and then pick signs.

Comment: That might be the best way.

Comment: Any thoughts about my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. First, like vasshu suggested, we find the first orthogonal vector Q by coming up with a system of equations based on the dot product. For this example the system would have variables a, b and c multiplied by the vector coefficients 1a+1.25b-0.518c = 0. Then we select arbitrary values for a, b and c such that the equation is satisfied, these will be the components of the new vector Q. In order to find the last vector R and ensure it respects the right hand rule we follow a similar approach but with the cross product, i.e P = QxR and solve for the coefficients again. Once we have all three vectors we normalize them all by dividing the values of each vector by the values of the vector respectively. And we have our basis.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from the equations that $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are pairwise orthogonal. Then a little fiddling shows all three vectors must have length 1. But $P$ doesn't have length 1, so you lose.

EDIT: Let me fill in some details. By hypothesis, $Q\perp R$. Since $P=Q\times R$ we have $P\perp Q$ and $P\perp R$. If $A=B\times C$ then $\|A\|=\|B\|\|C\|\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $B$ and $C$. If $B\perp C$ that formula becomes $\|A\|=\|B\|\|C\|$.

Thus, we have $\|P\|=\|Q\|\|R\|$, and from $R=P\times Q$ we have $\|R\|=\|P\|\|Q\|$. So $\|P\|=\|Q\|\|P\|\|Q\|$, and since $\|P\|\ne0$ we get $\|Q\|^2=1$, which implies $\|Q\|=1$.

By symmetry, we also get $\|P\|=1$ and $\|R\|=1$. But we are given $P = (1, 1.25, -0.518)$, so we don't have $\|P\|=1$, contradiction. Hence, it is impossible to find $Q,R$ with the desired properties.